# Sql Server 2008, Select dates of current week in a generic query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

How can I get the current week in a generic query, currently I can get a date range but I would like to get the current week in a dynamic way.

This is what I have:

```
WITH mycte AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2011-01-01' AS DATETIME) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 1
  FROM    mycte   
  WHERE   DateValue + 1 < '2021-12-31'
)
SELECT  DateValue
FROM    mycte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Based on todays date I want to get something like:

```
11-04-2013 11-05-2013 11-06-2013 11-07-2013 11-08-2013 11-09-2013 11-10-2013
```

Comment: For MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Does "Current" week start on Sunday?

Comment: Is there a specific database that you are targeting?  There could be database specific syntax that could be used and tagging with two databases complicates the question.

Comment: I can use mysql 5.1.32 or Sql Server 2008 and current week will start on Monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it in SQL Server

```
WITH weekdays AS 
(
  SELECT 0 day
  UNION ALL
  SELECT day + 1 FROM weekdays WHERE day < 6
)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, day, DATEADD(DAY, 2-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CONVERT (date, GETDATE())), CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))) date
    FROM weekdays
```

Output:

```
|       DATE |
|------------|
| 2013-11-04 |
| 2013-11-05 |
| 2013-11-06 |
| 2013-11-07 |
| 2013-11-08 |
| 2013-11-09 |
| 2013-11-10 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24593)** demo

In MySQL

```
SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY + INTERVAL day DAY date
  FROM
(
  SELECT 1 day UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 7
) w
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/24718)** demo

Comment: @Uuid A monthly version would look almost the same. You might already know (given your reputation > 300) that changing the scope of the question is not how SO works. If your question has been answered please consider to accept it. If you have another question just post it and other SO members or I will be happy to help you with it.

Comment: I will surely post another question but I already did the montly version, thanks peter.

Comment: @Uuid You're quite welcome and I'm glad you did it. Good luck and happy coding :)